# How can I get Visual Studio to connect to the Windows Store?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp, windows-store

I'm trying to create app packages, in Visual Studio 2015, to upload to the Windows Store, but every attempt to connect to the Store results in the error:

`An unexpected network error has occurred.  The app list cannot be refreshed.  Please retry by pressing the Refresh button.`

This operation seems idempotent: pressing "Refresh" lands me back in the same state.

I'll give a lot of detail about config and things I've tried below, but at this stage, I'm just after any method to get the app uploaded to the store.  If it has to be built on the command line, or if I have to produce an `.appxupload` by hand editing, that's fine.

I'm trying to do:

`Project > Store > Create App Packages`

and selecting "Yes" for "Do you want to build packages to upload to the Windows Store?"

I get the same error when trying to associate the app with the Store.  My understanding is that this step is just a convenience for pulling down app metadata, and I've tried to populate it all to the app manifest by hand, to no avail, apparently.

I have also tried selecting "No" and then bundling the symbol files with the produced `.appxbundle`, zipping up the file and renaming with an `.appxupload` extension, then uploading that by hand.

Depending whether I have selected `Compile with .NET Native tool chain` or not, the Windows store validation tells me either:

"You cannot submit pre-compiled .NET Native packages"
or
"This package wasn't built for submission to the Store.  Make sure you're uploading a Release build with the .NET Native tool chain enabled."

I'm running Visual Studio 2015, `Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3`, but I've also tried Visual Studio 2017 `Version 15.7.1` and Visual Studio 2017 Preview `Version 15.8.0 Preview 1.1` (suggested in various forums).

The app is a UWP update to an existing Windows 8.1 app already in the Store.

I'm signed in to Visual Studio with a valid developer account.

I note that when I try to connect through Visual Studio, the following URLs are requested in my proxy:

`https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=823107&clcid=0x409
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=780687&clcid=0x409
https://developer.microsoft.com`

Two redirects, landing eventually at the developer centre.

If anyone can suggest what configuration I may have missed, or an alternative way to get the app uploaded, or can see a way to advance down one of those paths that I've missed, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

This [article](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/12/15/building-an-app-for-a-3rd-party-how-to-package-their-store-app) shows how to create the appxupload package without the Store Package Creation Wizard.

I'd suggest to report the issue connecting to the store in the [VS feedback site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com).