# How can I manually package a UWP app for submission to the Windows Store?

Tags: uwp, msbuild, windows-store

I would like to build a UWP app that I can upload to the Windows Store, without relying on Visual Studio connecting to the Store directly.

I'm struggling to get the connection working, as detailed here:

[How can I get Visual Studio to connect to the Windows Store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50402007/how-can-i-get-visual-studio-to-connect-to-the-windows-store)

and would like to take that connection out of the equation.

Is there any description of what exactly needs to be in an `.appxupload` file for it to pass validation on the Store, and what tools can assist in building it?

I understand that it's a zip file containing symbol files and app packages for required architectures, but I'm unsure whether it needs to be code signed, populated with Windows Store metadata and so on.

In particular, hand assembled packages that I've tried to submit so far have failed validation as follows:

Depending whether I have selected Compile with .NET Native tool chain or not, the Windows store validation tells me either:

`You cannot submit pre-compiled .NET Native packages` 
or 
`This package wasn't built for submission to the Store. Make sure you're uploading a Release build with the .NET Native tool chain enabled.`

My current understanding is that .NET Native is some intermediate representation quite far down the compilation pipeline, but not yet generated into architecture specific instructions, but I can't tell from this pair of errors whether it's the required submission format or not.

Answer (score 1):

From the error I am guessing you are packaging a UWP with a fulltrust extension component, so you have both UWP .NET components as well as standard desktop .NET components.

For this type of project you need to use the VS Packaging Project in order to create the .appxupload file:

https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/12/04/extend-desktop-application-windows-10-features-using-new-visual-studio-application-packaging-project/#68e4hhVQHLo267pE.97

Also some additional info in this blog post:
https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/29/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-4/

Comment: I do have architecture specific dlls in the project.  Is it possible that's the issue?

(I've created the packaging project and tried to upload its output, with the same validation error.  It's possible I've misunderstood how to configure it.)

Comment: I'm getting the same validation error from the Store if I create a brand new UWP app using File > New > Project... then Visual C# > Windows Universal > Blank App

If I build that and upload, the Store still says `You cannot submit pre-compiled .NET Native packages`

Comment: With your blank app test, what file exactly are you uploading? The .appxupload file or something else?

Comment: I think I uploaded the `.appxbundle` in that instance, and didn't try with the `.appxupload`.  I'll have to verify in two days (don't currently have access to the machine).

My thinking was to try to narrow down the amount of packaged stuff, to try to focus on what's causing the specific error message, but if it needs the entire `.appxupload`, I'd better check again.

Thank you very much for your assistance.

Comment: At this point, I'm just trying to conduct experiments or ask questions to determine exactly what the error message means, and what the underlying issue is.  Really, my goal is just to get the app uploaded, and I'm trying to work around the fact that Visual Studio fails to connect to the Windows Store, so I'm trying to package the app by hand for submission, so a solution along either path would be very welcome.

Comment: OK, I see your other post now. Seems like we should get this connection issue solved first, then everything else should work automatically. I am reaching out to VS and Store folks to take a look.